# Combining 2 objects through a loop

Tags: javascript

```
let response = {
    data1: {
       names: ["John", "jim"]
    },
    data2: {
       ages: [34, 24]
    }
}
```

I want:

```
data: {
   names: ["John", "jim"],
   ages: [34,24]
}
```

Is there a way to merge these into 1 object without referencing `response.data1` and `response.data2`?  I know I can do `const newObj = {...response.data1, ...response.data2}` or `Object.assign({}, response.data1, response.data1)`...  Can I do via a `for in` loop?

Answer (score 2):

You could merge the values of the object using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) like this:

```
Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(response))
```

---

Explanation:

This is the syntax for Object.assign:  `Object.assign(target, source1, source2, ... etc)`. It basically takes all the properties from the *source* objects and updates the *target* object

The [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) bit returns the value of the `response` object. In this case, it's an array of objects like this:

```
[
  { names: ["John", "jim"] }, 
  { ages: [34, 24] }
]
```

You can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array and pass individual object as a parameter to `Object.assign()`

Here's a snippet:

```js
let response = {
  data1: {
    names: ["John", "jim"]
  },
  data2: {
    ages: [34, 24]
  }
}

const output = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(response))

console.log(output)
```

---

If it's too confusing you could use `reduce`:

```
Object.values(response)
      .reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, ...v }), {})
```

Or a simple loop:

```
const output = {}

for(const key in response)
  Object.assign(output, response[key])
```

Comment: I believe the question makes note that they are aware of the `Object.assign` solution, but that they specifically want to try to accomplish it with a loop.

Comment: @AlexanderNied that's not what they meant. They are saying they don't want to use the property name `data1` explicitly as it is dynamic and there could be unknown number of properties.

Comment: Ah sure, that's fair; that's probably the correct interpretation.

Comment: @AlexanderNied they said they were aware of _an_  `Object.assign` solution. There is no such thing as _the_ `Object.assign` solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge `data1` and `data2` using a `for in` loop, try this:

```js
let response = {
    data1: {
       names: ["John", "jim"]
    },
    data2: {
       ages: [34, 24]
    }
}
var result = {}
for (data in response) {
  if (response.hasOwnProperty(data)) {
    [key] = Object.keys(response[data])
    result[key] = response[data][key]
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

The way it works is by getting the keys of `data` and `data2`, then using those keys, it gets the values and adds it to `result`

Comment: Probably worth noting that, because `for...in` loops will go over _all_ properties of an object, including inherited ones, one generally will want to include a [.hasOwnProperty() check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) before proceeding with any processing.

Comment: I fixed it, is that better?